# Only ROC reported for predictive model

Tags: predictive-models, roc, calibration

I have just finished reading a medical paper that claims to have developed a **predictive** model but reported ROC alone without a calibration curve.

ROC seems to be useful for cases of binary **diagnosis**, which is quite different from prediction.

I understand that a model with good concordance can be calibrated, but calibration is not always easy, especially with class imbalance.

My original question was: Why not even *address* calibration in a paper on predictive modeling?

My new question is: why even report ROC at all?

I suspect it's because ROC AUC is between zero and one and therefore easy to report and understand whether it's good or bad...(not so with Brier score)